# How can I get the built-in display to pan as I move the mouse to the edges in dual display mode?

Tags: lubuntu, 13.10, gui, monitor

I have an Eeepc 900a with a display of 1024x600 running lubuntu 13.10. The VGA port will display at 1920x1080. I am able to use LXRandR 0.1.2 to set it to use both displays at the same time. How can I get the built-in display to pan as I move the mouse to the edges?

Command line solution is:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --panning 1920x1080 --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080
```